# Conflict google gms version in android studio?

Tags: android, ionic4, capacitor, gradle-dependencies

Where is the conflict of version google gms service in my dependencies:

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'org.apache.cordova:framework:7.0.0'
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
    // implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
    implementation "com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0"
    // implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    // implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

I run this project with ionic capacitor please help me.

When I want to run my project I get with this error:

```
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+
```

Comment: Instead of `10+` use specific version like `17.0.0`. It's recommended. Also you should upgrade your dependencies to latest version for *gms* and *firebase*

Comment: Hello, I overwrite my dependencies but doesn't work, I edit my question please help me.